# How to remove the rows which 90% of it's entries are less than certain threshold?

Tags: r

Given very big matrix, I need to remove the rows of that matrix which 90 % of it's entries are less than 20.
Would someone help to implement this in R ?

Comment: I think people here are expecting some [reproducible code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), in order to efficiently help you.

Comment: And people would prefer that you clearly define your problem the first time around....

Answer (score 4):

This might help you:

```
m <- matrix(1:20, nrow = 4)
m
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#[1,]    1    5    9   13   17
#[2,]    2    6   10   14   18
#[3,]    3    7   11   15   19
#[4,]    4    8   12   16   20
```

Now remove row all rows where 90 % of the row's entries are less than 2:

```
m[rowSums(m > 2) >= 0.9*ncol(m),]  
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#[1,]    3    7   11   15   19
#[2,]    4    8   12   16   20
```

Some explanation: `rowSums(m > 2)` counts how many entries in each row are greater than 2 for each row. `0.9*ncol(m)` is the threshold of 90 of the columns and these two are compared for each row and if it is TRUE, the row is selected, if it's FALSE, the row is dropped/removed.

Comment: +1 - I prefer a slight rejig to `m[rowSums(m >2)/ncol(m) >= 0.9,]` , but you say /təˈmeɪtoʊz/ and I say /təˈmɑːtoʊz/” so...

Comment: Thanks @thelatemail, I also like your suggestion :)

Comment: @beginneR, thanks, but this is not right answer. what I mean with 90% of enteris is that, if I have 100 columns, I want to remove rows which 90 enteries of it are less than 2.

Comment: You can easily adapt my code to your specific needs which were not well specified in your question. See what happens when you chAnge the >= to < or when you replace 0.9 with 0.1 and so on.

Comment: Should'nt rowSums add up all numbers>2 in that row rather than counting them? How can one get sum of all numbers>2 in a row?

Comment: @rnso, `m > 2` should create a logical vector which is then summed up by row. I think what you mean is `rowSums(m[m > 2])`, correct?

Comment: @beginneR: OK. So all TRUEs are counted or summed. But rowSums(m[m > 2]) does not work: Error in rowSums(m[m > 2]) :   'x' must be an array of at least two dimensions

Comment: @rnso, right, in that case, you'd have to use `apply(m, 1, function(x) sum(x[x>2]))`. But that's not what was asked in the question, if I undestood correctly